# splitting text further while preserving line breaks

Tags: python, string, split, nltk, tokenize

I am splitting text `para` and preserving the line breaks `\n` using the following

```
from nltk import SpaceTokenizer
para="\n[STUFF]\n  comma,  with period. the new question? \n\nthe\n  \nline\n new char*"
sent=SpaceTokenizer().tokenize(para)
```

Which gives me the following
`print(sent)`

```
['\n[STUFF]\n', '', 'comma,', '', 'with', 'period.', 'the', 'new', 'question?', '\n\nthe\n', '', '\nline\n', 'new', 'char*']
```

My goal is to get the following output

```
['\n[STUFF]\n', '', 'comma', ',', '', 'with', 'period', '.', 'the', 'new', 'question', '?', '\n\nthe\n', '', '\nline\n', 'new', 'char*']
```

That is to say, I would like to *split* the  `'comma,'` into  `'comma'`, `','` *split* the `'period.'` into `'period'`, `'.'`  *split* the `'question?'` into `'question'`, `'?'` `while` preserving the `\n`

I have tried `word_tokenize` and it will achieve splitting `'comma'`, `','` etc but does not preserve `\n`

What can I do to further split `sent` as shown above while preserving `\n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per @randy suggestion to look https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split

```
import re
para = re.split(r'(\W+)', '\n[STUFF]\n  comma,  with period. the new question? \n\nthe\n  \nline\n new char*')
print(para)
```

Output (close to what I am looking for)

```
['', '\n[', 'STUFF', ']\n  ', 'comma', ',  ', 'with', ' ', 'period', '. ', 'the', ' ', 'new', ' ', 'question', '? \n\n', 'the', '\n  \n', 'line', '\n ', 'new', ' ', 'char', '*', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split is probably what you want.

From the looks of your desired output however, you're going to need to process the string a bit more than just applying a single function to it.

I would start by replacing all of the `\n` with a string like `new_line_goes_here` before splitting the string up, and then replacing `new_line_goes_here` with `\n` once it's all split up.